# Python - Extracting a list of identifiers and corresponding values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for advice on the best method for sorting my dataset.

I have the following input ("data.txt"):

```
100    G(1,2)            1.0943        
100    G(1,3)            1.0933
101    G(1,2)            1.5147        
101    G(1,3)            1.2372
101    G(1,4)            1.0955
... (10,000)
```

The ideal output is a text file with columns:

```
 G(1,2)        G(1,3)         G(1,4)
 1.0943        1.0933         1.0955
 1.5147        1.2372
```

My first thought is to create a dictionary with multiple values - where each 'G(x,x)' is a key and the corresponding number is a value.

Would this be the best way to approach this, or is there some other python function that would make sorting more efficient?

*Thanks to everyone for your suggestions - I'm looking into utilizing/learning about the `itertools.groupby` function as suggested by a couple of users below. The pandas resorting approach is also really helpful.*

Comment: Probably a better way than this. But if you were to have a dictionary with G(x,x) as keys, better to have one key for each G(x,x), then the values of the dict as a list of matching numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
import itertools
data = [[b for b in c if b] for c in [re.split("\s+", i.strip('\n')) for i in open('file.txt')] if c]
new_final_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[1][-2]), key=lambda x:x[1])]
final_data = {a:[[c for c in i if re.findall('\d+\.\d+', c)][0] for i in b] for a, b in new_final_data}
print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
{'G(1,3)': ['1.0933', '1.2372'], 'G(1,4)': ['1.0955'], 'G(1,2)': ['1.0943', '1.5147']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it as a transpose function, then a groupby. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=transpose

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Make sure to edit any relevant information from the link in here as the answer should be stand-alone even if the link becomes obsolete. Links should be used for crediting, referencing or further reading, and not as a search hunt to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In straight python (use a shell):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict    

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.match('.*(G\(\d,\d\))\s*(.*)', line)
        g = match.group(1)
        datum = float(match.group(2))
        data[g].append(datum)


for g in data:
    data[g].sort()

# do something with data.
```

Answer (score 1):

The pandas approach would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.txt', names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df = df[['col2', 'col3']]
df = df.pivot(columns = 'col2', values = 'col3')
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
df = df.to_csv(r'output.txt', index = False, sep = '\t')
```

Output:

```
G(1,2)  G(1,3)  G(1,4)
1.0943  1.0933  1.0955
1.5147  1.2372
```